# Filtering out recurring apointments on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, calendar, windows-phone-8.1

When I get all the appointmens in a specific timeframe with findAppointmentsAsync and there is a recurring apointment, there seems to be no apparent way to only get one appointment for the whole series instead of getting one appointment for each recurrence.
So if there is an appointment that recurs every monday and I get the appointments of 2 years I get this appointment for every monday, so 104 appointments.
Each of these appointments has the info that this appointment recurs every monday, so I would only need one appointment instance to get all the information.

Has anyone an idea on how to filter the recurrences out?

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Comment: Well there doesn't seem to be function or parameter to do it. The FindAppointmentOptions Class doesn't seem to have any option for this neither and the Appointment Class itself doesn't seem to have any attribute to do this too....